# Make a list of all Textbox values in a form

Tags: vb.net

I asked a question before, related to this topic. I wanted to know how to make a loop that adds together all of the textbox.text values in a form. This is the response I got, and it works perfectly.

```
sum = 0
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            If Integer.TryParse(txt.Text, i) Then
                sum = sum + i
        End If
    Next
```

What I want to know is how can I, using the same button, get the values of each text box in a form, and put them all together in one list/array?

It's quite a simple problem, but I just can't find the exact syntax for this anywhere.

Also, if a use a similar loop, but do `list.Add(text)`, it just breaks the first loop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the parsed integers to a `List(Of Int32)`:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Int32)
For Each txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Dim num As Int32 = 0
    If Integer.TryParse(txt.Text, num) Then
      list.Add(num)
    End If
Next
Dim sum = list.Sum() ' easier ;-)
```

The cast to `TextBox` is not needed because `ctrl` is already a `TextBox` thanks to `OfType`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I wanted this to make a list of strings?

Comment: @JackOubridge; then declare it as `List(of String)` and add `num.ToString()`. But of course you can't use `list.Sum` at the end if there are just strings. I would convert them to strings where yu want to show them, not in the storage.

Comment: Nice, that works great. Is there a way for me to reference certain values of the list on a different form? I tried using `Form1.list(2)` for example, but it returns nothing.

Comment: You can either pass this list to the other form via constructor (or method/property) or you could make it a public property in `Form1`. But then `Form2` needs to have access to the current instance of `Form1`, for example by passing it via constructor to `Form2`. I prefer passing only what you need, so the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim listOfTextBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList()
Dim listOfValue = listOfTextBox.Select(Function(e) Integer.Parse(e.Text))
Dim sum = listOfValue.Sum()
```

Comment: So you suggest to remove the `Integer.TryParse`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd say it's not clear what should happen when the Text property can't be integer parsed. Your solution will ignore those which can't; this one will throw an exception `Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: @djv: sure, but user input should be validated and even OP used `TryParse`

Comment: @TimSchmelter right. I'd rather validate at entry then there is no need for try, and the sum can be done in a single chain of lambda linq. Either way